# How do you do exception management with delayed job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

My application needs to parse a user-generated CSV file. And, once uploaded, the application will queue it in delayed job to be processed. My question is, how do you usually handle the exceptions that might happen during the content parsing stage? Do you store all the error messages in exception-objects before display it to user?

Thank you.

Comment: I know this probably sounds obvious, but you'd likely want to have conditions in your method that catch all oddities and do something smart with them. If you're unsure what kind of errors you'll face, then log and review later, otherwise, rescue block with the appropriate exceptions should work.

Answer (score 0):

As the job is delayed, I would like to give all the errors in the CSV file at once.  So that users do not end up iterating multiple times (fixing 1 error at a time).

One thing you can do is store all errors in a DB (in an suitable object).  This would also enable to you analyze what kind of errors users are generally having and help them in reducing those.